# Flutter : Arc connecting two circle buttons

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I achieve this in flutter dart.

1. I have 2 circle elevated buttons.
2. I am trying to connect them with arcs - Is there a way i can draw arcs connecting two buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/graphview
you can try the package above. it should help you achieve this.

Comment: i reviewed this package , but the links between nodes are straight line where as i am in need of arcs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the arc first and place your button over the points of it. Please check below link to draw the arc.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/26483389-flutter-canvas-api-getting-started

Though if you sti facing difficulty, i can try writing the code and share it with you.